# Sort arrays within an array, by name

Tags: php, arrays

Input:

```
$sql = array(

    array("id"=>"47", "name"=>"Jason", "device"=>"idevice"),
    array("id"=>"49", "name"=>"uniKornn", "device"=>"idevice"),
    array("id"=>"50", "name"=>"jacob", "device"=>"idevice")
)
```

Output:

```
$sql = array(

    array("id"=>"50", "name"=>"jacob", "device"=>"idevice"),
    array("id"=>"47", "name"=>"Jason", "device"=>"idevice"),
    array("id"=>"49", "name"=>"uniKornn", "device"=>"idevice")
)
```

I want to set the order of the array $sql, by name, and case-insensitive.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried using `sort($sql)` but that didn't work...

Comment: How about ksort($sql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}

usort($sql, build_sorter('name'));
```

EDIT: For case-insensitive:

Option 1:

```
function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcasecmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}

usort($sql, build_sorter('name'));
```

Option 2:

```
function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp(strtolower($a[$key]), strtolower($b[$key]));
    };
}

usort($sql, build_sorter('name'));
```

Full Code:

```
<?php

$sql = array(
    array("id"=>"47", "name"=>"Jason", "device"=>"idevice"),
    array("id"=>"49", "name"=>"uniKornn", "device"=>"idevice"),
    array("id"=>"50", "name"=>"jacob", "device"=>"idevice")
);

function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp(strtolower($a[$key]), strtolower($b[$key]));
    };
}

usort($sql, build_sorter('name'));

foreach ($sql as $item) {
    echo $item['id'] . ', ' . $item['name'] .', ' . $item['device'] . "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: This works, but it is case-sensitive. It orders by A-Z a-z. I want it to be case-insensitive

Answer (score -1):

Or short version for strings

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
     return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
 }

usort($array, "cmp");
```